# vssadmin execute from Cygwin shell, class not registered

Tags: windows, cygwin

Copying the Original question from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/vssadmin-execute-from-cygwin-shell-class-not/bc28d5f9-a0ef-41f1-b757-280e8fc9941a?db=5), as some genious decided to close it.

> I am using VSS for a Windows 2008 R2 machine.
>
> I can execute "vssadmin List Shadows"   and other commands
>   successfully in  Windows Cmd shell.
>
> But I need to execute it through a Cygwin shell,   for remote access
>   purpose.
>
> I always got " Class not registered." error in the Cygwin shell,   I
>   checked the path and variables. The variables are the same. The Cmd
>   shell paths are all in the Cygwin shell.
>
> Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just take care that the cygwin build ist the proper arch. When installing cygwin one can either user the x86 or the x86_64 installer (or the -a x86[_64] command line switch). By calling a 32bit cygwin bash from inside a 64bit cmd on a 64bit Windows, the environment will be switched to 32bit and inside that vssadmin will have no access to the 64bit libraries/services it requires.